# JMeter HTTP Request not able to GET response from bestbuy.com but ALL other sites are working

Tags: jmeter

My JMeter script is not getting a response from bestbuy.com but all other sites are working. Is there anything special about this site? Can someone try this out and let me know if it's working or not for your installation?

Other E-Commerce sites are working. So far I've tried amazon.com, newegg.com and a bunch of other sites.

Any and all pointers are appreciated.

I've tried this on mac book air and on Windows 11 with Jmeter version 5.5 and JDK version 20 and Java version 18. [image: JMeter HTTP Request Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. It turns out that my "Header Manager" that I got from Blazemeter plugin was not correct. Once I fixed that it's working now.

Here are the screenshots of the header manager. The first one is the one that was NOT working. And the second one is the one that is working.[NON Working Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZk1B.png)

[image: Working Header Manager]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [configure JMeter to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), given you send the same request as the browser does you should get the same response.

Most probably you didn't add a [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) like [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) so the site doesn't let you in considering you a scraping bot or indexing robot or something like this.

Also certain websites have sophisticated anti-bot protection and heavily rely on JavaScript, according to [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/) JMeter cannot execute JavaScript so if this is the case - you will either need to consider using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) or look for another tool.